# Wrong XACML function identifier in output of Eclipse ALFA plugin

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, alfa

The XACML output for any-of-any seems to be wrong:

```
FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of-any"
```

is what I get and

```
FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:any-of-any"
```

is what AutzZForce-core wants.

I already uncommented this line in `system.alfa`, but there is still the same issue.

```
function anyOfAny = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:any-of-any" : function anyAtomicOrBag anyAtomicOrBag* -> boolean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of different things.

1. First of all, `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of-any` is a valid XACML identifier. It is normative and mandatory in XACML 3.0. It is planned for deprecation in future versions but for now, it is still part of the standard. See the [XACML spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html) for details.
2. As you point out the new, preferred identifier is  `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:any-of-any`. Given the way ALFA is built, you can change the identifier yourself in `system.alfa`. To do so, open the file and locate the value you do not care for (in this case `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of-any`) and replace it with the newer identifier.

### Original

```
function anyOfAny = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of-any" : function anyAtomicOrBag anyAtomicOrBag* -> boolean
```

### New

```
function anyOfAny = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:any-of-any" : function anyAtomicOrBag anyAtomicOrBag* -> boolean
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, I already did 2., but I still get `FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of-any` in the transformated file.

Comment: Hmm strange... Let me check on my end

Comment: I have version 1.0.2 of the plugin. Maybe that's relevant.

Comment: Do you found something?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that some functions have been hardcoded. I have notified the product owner and they should fix it in a future release. In the meantime, use XSLT to post-process the XML that is generated or ask AuthZForce to make their PDP XACML 3.0-conformant